# Boolean insertion without quotes - Liquibase over MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean, liquibase

I need to insert new record on this users table with Liquibase. It works well on PostgreSQL, but when it comes to MySQL the SQL output has quotes for the boolean field (u_administrator). Like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (u_name, ..., u_administrator) VALUES ('Administrator',..., '1')
```

---

```
    <changeSet author="jmartins" id="AdminInsertion">
        <insert tableName="users" dbms="postgresql">
            <column name="u_name" value="Administrator"/>
            ...
            <column name="u_administrator" value="true"/>
        </insert>
        <insert tableName="users" dbms="mysql">
            <column name="u_name" value="Administrator"/>
            ...
            <column name="u_administrator" value="1"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
```

So I can I force liquibase to output "u_administrator" without quotes so it can insert correctly on MySQL. Do I need to go for a < sql> custom command?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Use valueBoolean instead of value to tell liquibase it needs to use the database-specific value for a boolean value.